# MVC 5 project with solution, packages and nuget

Tags: c#, github, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on NetCollab which is similar to WebCollab. I m working on this project on Computer A.

https://github.com/fatagun/NetCollab

When I clone this project from another computer, Computer B, i have to restore packages.

Then I see lot of items that i will have to commit, which shouldn't be there actually.

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `.gitignore` file could look like:

```
#OS junk files
[Tt]humbs.db
*.DS_Store

#Visual Studio files
*.[Oo]bj
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.[Cc]ache
*.ilk
*.log
*.lib
*.sbr
*.sdf
*.opensdf
*.unsuccessfulbuild
ipch/
[Oo]bj/
[Bb]in
[Dd]ebug*/
[Rr]elease*/
Ankh.NoLoad

#MonoDevelop
*.pidb
*.userprefs

#Tooling
_ReSharper*/
*.resharper
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*
*.sass-cache

#Project files
[Bb]uild/

#Subversion files
.svn

# Office Temp Files
~$*

# vim Temp Files
*~

#NuGet
packages/
*.nupkg

#ncrunch
*ncrunch*
*crunch*.local.xml

# visual studio database projects
*.dbmdl

#Test files
*.testsettings
```

This will prevent git from trying to commit files that aren't necessary.

Comment: This is already in .gitignore. ALso, how do i remove the packagesnow?

Comment: You didn't say you already have a `.gitignore` file. Maybe just try removing them from your repository? This may help: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data Btw if you still see them then it might be that your `.gitignore` file isn't valid...? Or it's not read or set to different one. Check your git settings for this project.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an ignore to the `packages` folder so they are not commited (except you want that).

To do that add a `.gitignore` file to your project root directory and add the `packages` folder to that file:

```
/PATH/packages/
```

See follwoing link for more details: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore